# How to debug unit test while developping a package in Julia

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia

Say I develop a package with a limited set of dependencies (for example, LinearAlgebra).
In the Unit testing part, I might need additional dependencies (for instance, CSV to load a file). I can configure that in the `Project.toml` all good.

Now from there and in VS Code, how can I debug the Unit tests? I tried running the "runtests.jl" in the debugger; however, it unsurprisingly complains that the CSV package is unavailable.

I could add the CSV package (as a temporary solution), but I would prefer that the debugger run with the configuration for the unit testing; how can I achieve that?

As requested, here is how it can be reproduced (it is not quite minimal, but instead I used a commonly used package as it give confidence the package is not the problem). We will use DataFrames and try to execute the debugger for its unit tests.

- Make a local version of `DataFrames` for the purpose of developing a feature in it. I execute `dev DataFrames` in a new REPL.
- Select the correct environment (in `.julia/dev/DataFrames`) through the VS-code user interface.
- Execute the "proper" unit testing by executing `test DataFrames` at the pkg prompt. Everything should go smoothly.
- Try to execute the tests directly (open the `runtests.jl` and use the "Run" button in vs-code). I see some errors of the type:

```
LoadError: ArgumentError: Package CategoricalArrays not found in current path:
- Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("CategoricalArrays")` to install the CategoricalArrays package.
```

which is consistent with CategoricalArrays being present in the `[extras]` section of the Project.toml but not present in the `[deps]`.

- Finally, instead of the "Run" command, execute the "Run and Debug". I encounter similar errors here is the first one:

```
Test Summary: | Pass  Total
merge         |   19     19
        PASSED: index.jl
        FAILED: dataframe.jl
LoadError: ArgumentError: Package DataStructures not found in current path:
- Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("DataStructures")` to install the DataStructures package.
```

So I can't debug the code after the part requiring the extras packages.

- After all that I delete this package with the command `free DataFrames` at the pkg prompt.

I see the same behavior in my package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not certain I understand your question, but I think you might be looking for the [TestEnv](https://github.com/JuliaTesting/TestEnv.jl) package. It allows you to activate a temporary environment containing the `[extras]` dependencies. The [discourse announcement](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/ann-testenv-jl-activate-your-test-enviroment-so-you-can-use-your-test-dependencies/65739) contains a good description of the use cases.

Comment: Yeah, that's the idea. Although ideally, I would have liked to have it more integrated with VS code.

Answer (score 2):

Your `runtest.jl` file should contain all necessary imports to run tests.

Hence you are expected to have in your `runtests.jl` file lines such as:

```
using YourPackageName
using CSV

# the lines with tests now go here.
```

This is a standard in Julia package layout. For an example have a look at any mature Julia such as `DataFrames.jl` (https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFrames.jl/blob/main/test/runtests.jl).

Comment: Thank you for looking into it. The ```runtests.jl``` is working fine on its own. using the ```[extra]``` from the ```Project.toml```. Like ```DataFrames.jl``` does here  (https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFrames.jl/blob/961b916d345fd840936deb4643c6334eb66ffbf8/Project.toml#L47) it adds a dependency to ```Logging``` that does not exist in the project itself (only for testing). And the testing works fine too (executing ```test myPackage``` from the ```pkg>``` prompt without issue). Only I could not figure how to run these tests in the debugger.

Comment: Perhaps MVP would help. However there are two issues: (1) selecting the proper environment in VS Code (use  `Pkg.status()` to check - perhaps this is a good idea to add this in the beginning of your `runtests.jl` file) and (2) runtests.jl is in a different folder than the project and hence some resources may be in different locations. Otherwise you should be able to run tests in VS Code debugger.

Comment: What is MVP? I will look into (1), I am already doing (2).

Comment: Sorry I meant Minimal Working Example - MWE :-) https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example   all those acronims...

Comment: Good point; I added a way to reproduce the behavior in the question. It is not quite minimal but should ensure the problem is not with the package but rather with me not knowing how to launch the debugger adequately.